# Is there a way to generate woocommerce products from .jpeg images?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dynamically-generated, auto-generate, data-entry

A customer of mine sent me some images (2300) for 600 products that he wants to create. The images are all .jpeg format and the image name is like this:
SKU - name - material - dimensions. There is also a number at the end of the image name, if it is going to be used for the same product as another image. This is a WordPress site with woocommerce. Is there any way to automatically generate the products using the images and info from their filenames?

Answer (score 0):

I think your option is to write a custom piece of code that scans the directory with the images and using the rule you know (the filename contains some info about the product) you could use woocommerce classes to insert the new products.

You are for sure missing the price, which is required by Woocommerce to enable selling.